# How to stop a timer upon keydown?

Tags: javascript

I have a text input box, which updates the 'ticket' with my the input when the timer finishes, instead of every keystroke which was the previous behaviour. However this causes a reload of the text input often while I am still using it.

I believe the best solution would be for the timer to reset every keydown event, but the few solutions I've tried haven't worked well, so I'd like to see if that's what is the most straightforward route to taker in my situation.

Relevant Code Below

```
   strValue: {
  get: function () {
    return this.attachment.strValue;
  },
  set: function (val) {
   let self = this; setTimeout(function(){ return self.updateAttachment([self.attachment.id, { strValue: val }]) },8000)  },
},
```

Full section of code:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allDocumentTypeGroups', 'currentTicketCaseFiles', 'activeAttachmentIndex', 'showAttachmentsPreview', 'activeAttachments']),

    attachmentAcceptedLabel() {
      return this.attachmentAccepted ? this.t('accepted') : this.t('ignored');
    },
    attachmentAccepted: {
      get: function () {
        return !this.attachment.ignoreAttachment;
      },
      set: function (val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { ignoreAttachment: !val }]);
      },
    },
    documentType: {
      get: function() {
        return this.attachment.documentTypeId;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { documentTypeId: val }]);
      },
    },
    approveAttachment: {
      get: function() {
        return this.attachment.approvedAttachment;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        return this.updateAttachment([this.attachment.id, { approvedAttachment: val }]);
      },
    },

    strValue: {
      get: function () {
        return this.attachment.strValue;
      },
      set: function (val) {
        let timer;
        if(timer){
          clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        let self = this;
        timer = setTimeout(function(){ return self.updateAttachment([self.attachment.id, { strValue: val }]) },8000)  },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Do you need the input to "reload" when the timer actually finishes or it is happening and you don't know why? I will not discuss UX, but your case seems unusual. A submit button is not better?

Comment: @ErnestoStifano No, but it's a side effect of the PATCH request that is sent. I believe a submit button is better, but have been instructed to do it this way. So I would preferably have the submission occur without the reload, but as I've been unsuccessful it seems my best option is to just ensure it happens once I'm no longer typing, hence the timer being reset every keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **clearTimeout(timer)** as shown below:

```js
   
let timer;   
   
   strValue: {
  get: function () {
    return this.attachment.strValue;
  },
  set: function (val) {
  if(timer){
    clearTimeout(timer);
   }
   let self = this; 
   timer = setTimeout(function(){ return self.updateAttachment([self.attachment.id, { strValue: val }]) },8000)  },
},


},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've attached a fuller picture of my code in an edit, maybe you could tell me the best place within that to declare the let? It's throwing me a couple of errors as I input your code

Comment: Add if condition before calling clearTimeout as I added in the above code

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple implementation of a throttled input. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const ticket = document.getElementById('ticket');

const threshold = 2000;

let timeout = null;

const onKeydownHandler = () => {
  // CLEAR PREVIOUS TIMEOUT WHEN A KEY IS PRESSED.
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  // "RESTART" THE TIMEOUT.
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    // UPDATE YOUR VALUE HERE.
    ticket.innerText = `Ticket Value: ${input.value}`;
  }, threshold);
};

input.addEventListener('keydown', onKeydownHandler);



// REMOVE THIS
(() => {
  const counter = document.getElementById('counter');
  let interval = null;
  let count = threshold;
  input.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    count = threshold;
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      count -= 50;
      counter.innerText = `Time Left: ${count}ms`;
      if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 50);
  });
  counter.innerText = `Time Left: ${count}ms`;
})();
// REMOVE THIS
```

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id='input' type='text' placeholder='Start writing...'></input>

<div>
  <span id='ticket'>Ticket Value:</span>
</div>



<!--REMOVE THIS-->
<div>
  <span id='counter'></span>
</div>
<!--REMOVE THIS-->
```